# Sieving by composite moduli

Tags: nt.number-theory, sieve-theory

A traditional sieve gives a bound on the number of integers $n$ in an interval (say $I=[0,N]$) such that $$n\not\in S_p \mod p$$ for every prime $p$ in a set $\mathcal{P}$, where $S_p\subset \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$.

What happens if instead we are given a set $\mathcal{M}$ of composite moduli, and asked to give an upper bound on the number of integers $n$ in $I$ such that
$$n\not\in S_m \mod m\;\;\; \forall m\in \mathcal{M},$$ where $S_m\subset \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$? Is there any literature on the matter? Note the elements of $\mathcal{M}$ need not be pairwise coprime.

Comment: If the set is finite and not redundant (for each m there is number sieved only by m), the standard elementary arguments should work on a large scale just like with primes. Remember to redefine Eulers phi so that phi(m)=m-1.  Were you thinking about short intervals?  Gerhard "Jacobsthal May Play A Role" Paseman, 2020.07.06.

Comment: Oops. There is a twist. One does have to consider common divisors of the m_i.  I will think further on this.  I have no references at present for this problem for composite moduli. Gerhard "Found More To Throw Out" Paseman, 2020.07.06.

Comment: Is $S_p$ the set of integers *not divisible* by $p$?

Comment: No, it's just the set of excluded classes. Call it $\Omega_p$ if you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

1. A. Sarközy, A note on the arithmetic form of the large sieve,
   Sudia Sci Math Hungarica  27, 1992, 83--95

covers the literature until then (there are some later results, adapting this as needed.)

2. I. Ruzsa, On the small sieve. II. Sifting by composite numbers
   Journal of Number Theory 14 (2), 1982, 260--268